# How to fix Uncaught TypeError: this.filterProjects is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, this, arrow-functions

I'm trying to do a filter gallery projects using jquery inside es6 and i'm

having this error: Uncaught TypeError: this.filterProjects is not a

function.I guess this error has to do with this keyword but I'm not sure how

to fix

```
import $ from 'jquery';

class ProjectsModal{
    constructor(){
        this.btnCategories=$(".our-works__btn-categories h3");
        this.projects=$(".our-works__images li");
        this.events();
    }

    events(){
        this.btnCategories.click(this.filterByCategory);
    }

    filterByCategory(){
        var category=$(this).text().toLowerCase();
        this.filterProjects(category);
    }
filterProjects(category){
        if (category=='all') {
            this.projects.fadeIn('slow');
        } else {
            this.projects.each(function(){
                if (!$(this).hasClass(category)) {
                    $(this).hide();
                } else {
                    $(this).fadeIn('slow');
                }
            });
        }
    }

}

export default ProjectsModal;
```

Comment: not really convinced that it is a good idea to mix jQuery in an ES6 object, jQuery use a `$(this)`  different from  `this`  representing the object

Comment: When did you get the error. I have ran your code, but it's fine